# What does this line mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar

> What is its significance for the enrichment of your knowledge and skills in your chosen course?

English isn't my native, so, correct me if I am wrong.
I can't really understand what this mean, yes the *importance of skills in my course*, but I can't get a straight to the point about what the question is asking.
Is it maybe because its not properly arranged?
Or can someone translate this to me in a simpler manner so I can create an answer subjectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is its significance for the enrichment of your knowledge and skills in your chosen course?

Damn. The author of this sentence seems to be struggling with English as well. That looks like it's just a complicated way of saying: "how does it improve your knowledge and skills". I don't know what "chosen course" means in this case - some more context might help.

Comment: It is for my OJT narrative report, so maybe he meant it to be something like > How will your OJT improve you skills in IT?

Comment: @AdorableVB Your answer will be "To write better English than your questions."

Answer (score 1):

> What is its significance for the enrichment of your knowledge and skills in your chosen course?

Lets try some simplifying this sentence to extract some meaning.

"Knowledge and Skill in your chosen course" can be equated to how well you would perform in a course of study which you have chosen.

"The enrichment of ..." means "the improvement of ..." in relation to education.

"What is the significacance for ..." possibly should of been written "What is the significance of ...", which makes more sense. This can also be express as "Why is ... important".

So, to re-write the sencence:

> Why is improving your knowledge and skills in your chosen course important?

Comment: this could be a deduction, but I already interpreted it to : *• What is the significance of the subject in the enrichment of your knowledge and skills learned from the course?*

Answer (score 0):

'What is it's significance' = what is the impact/help/furthering

'for the enrichment in your knowledge and skills = how does it add to your abilities

''in your chosen course' = not just general abilities, but those pertaining to your focused aim.

For example you are trying to learn a language...How does a given thing help you specifically with that goal?

Another  interpretation: What is the impact of this in you gaining skills in your field? How helpful is it to your aim?